# Typescript wont exclude file

Tags: typescript

Hey everyone I am trying to exclude a file form dist folder but whatever I do, the excluded file always compiled into dist folder, I know this question been asked many many times on stack overflow and I tried to follow other guys examples but no success. Here is my minimal setup to explain what is going on:

```
tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES6",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "importHelpers": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist/types",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/a.ts"]
}
```

here is my folder structure:

```
-src
   - a.ts
   - b.ts
- dist
   - a.ts <----- should not be there
   - b.ts
```

here is my files context:

```
a.ts
const name:string = "typescript"

b.ts
const name:string = "javascript"
```

Whatever I do, the `a.ts` file wont be excluded from dist folder. I do suspect I am doing something wrong but, I tried many examples base on the answers on StackOverflow but none of them help me. Can someone shed some light here?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so, then TypeScript might _also_ be running from within VS (and ignoring your `tsconfig.json` file, as it will use TypeScript MSBuild properties from your `.csproj` instead).

Comment: As a workaround or quick-fix, just add a new step to your build process that deletes `dist\a.ts` after a build completes.

Comment: `tsconfig.js` <-- Is your file actually named `tsconfig.js` instead of `tsconfig.json`? If so, then that's (at least part of) your problem: TypeScript only recognises the filename `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Sorry for `tsconfig.js`, I updated my question by fixing `tsconfig.js` to `tsconfig.json`. However, I am using webstorm editor and you may be right, I will check the Webstorm settings... I didn't think about this!!!

Comment: Is the excluded module used? If so, it will always be part of the output.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is not with tsconfig.json configurations rather with WebStorm editor. Thanks to @Dai comment, I was able to find the answer to this issue! However, WebStorm do not respect excluded and included files in tsconfig and it's a common problem with this editor! To fix it, go to `settings -> Languages&Frameworks` and in options filed enter `--`.  I am not sure why but it worked for me. If it dosent work for you, try to google "webstrom do not exclude files from tsconfig" and you will get a lot results on this issue!

[image]

Comment: It says "TypeScript: Bundled" - but what other options are in that drop-down?

Comment: `1 : Bundled
2 : ~\applications\gateway\node_modules\typescript
3 : Select`

Comment: What happens if you configure it to use your main TypeScript instance? (presumably the `npm` one?)

Comment: if I run `npm run tsc` the excluded files are respected as it should be...

Comment: Right, but we knew that - but does the same thing (i.e. the desired behaviour) happen when you configure WebStorm to use the same TypeScript instance then?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by  `same TypeScript instance`. Every new project I start, I  click on check box which says `TypeScript Language Service` and `Recompile on change` and my TS works . This is the only config options I have in WebStorm.

Comment: You said there's a third option: "Select", which I assume lets you browse to select the `tsc` npm script to use.

Comment: I got you... When I click on third options which is `select` I am getting a folder explorer ( not sure what folder I have to select there) but if I select the second option `~\applications\gateway\node_modules\typescript` the excluded and included files are respected also... I just tried and `a.ts` is not in `dist` folder..

Comment: Thank you Dai for your help, I am really appreciated it... learned a lot today about TS!!!